laravel filament auth()->user() returns null from helper file
I'm working on a Laravel application and using the Filament admin panel. I created a custom helper function to check user roles and access, but when I call auth()->user() inside this helper function, it returns null. Here is the code for my custom helper function:
    function checkUserRole()
    {
        $user = auth()->user();
        if ($user && $user->role == 'admin') {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

Additional Context:

I'm using Laravel 8.
Filament admin panel is being used for the admin
interface.
The custom helper function is defined in a file that is
included in the composer.json autoload section.


Make sure that route is protected through auth middleware.Are you sure you are using User model. In case of any other model you need to specify custom-guard.

its using user model and middleware is also correct, I can get auth()->user() from resource , but not from a global helper

you can use the facade Auth::user()it's the same as the helper

@francisco Already tried it but same result
